# Sending an email by adding cc and to fields in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Hi in contact us i am sending mails to different ids by adding them in CC but while sending an email all the emails are displaying in "TO" option the mail ids which i have mentioned in CC it should display in CC only but it is combing with To email id.How to differentiate TO and CC emails.

```
function send_mails($email)
{
     $name = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $description = $this->input->post('text');
        $subject=$this->input->post('subject');         

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'example@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'YYYY', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'newline'  =>"\r\n",
    'crlf' =>"\r\n",
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message            = array();


$message[] = 'Username  :  '.trim($name).' ';
$message[] = 'Phone Number :  '.trim($phone).' ';
$message[] = 'Description :  '.trim($description).' ';
$message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from($from_email);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->cc('info@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            if ($this->email->send())
        {
           $this->flash->success('Thank you for contacting us we will get back to you soon!</div>');
            redirect('contact');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->flash->success('There is error in sending mail! Please try again later');
            redirect('contact');
        }
}
```

Here in TO address there is only one Email id that should display in TO Field only.
And in CC there are two Email ids they both should display in cc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use array while doing cc.

```
$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->from($from_email);
$this->email->to($to_email);
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$this->email->cc($list);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Please try this and let me know if you have still the same error.

Comment: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.

Comment: Just one small problem the message is displaying in single line it is not coming one by one all the message list is displaying in single line only.

Comment: Okay, Use `$this->email->set_mailtype("html");` and use Html `<br>` to get in another line.

Comment: Stored the message in array and passed that array in message field you can check in my code

Comment: use `$message = implode('<br>', $message);`

Comment: Geeting email but not getting message

Comment: Adding this $message = implode('<br>', $message); not getting emails

Comment: Any idea of that

Comment: I am not sure what wrong in this code, Than also please check error logs and let me know.

Comment: $message = implode('<br>', $message);  if i use this then the message is not displaying

Comment: Please use this. `$message = htmlentities(implode('<br>', $message));`

Comment: $message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
 $message = implode('<br>', $message);  If i combine this both then i am not getting the message field

Answer (score 0):

```
      $this->email->initialize(array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_user' => 'email',
        'smtp_pass' => 'pwd',
        'smtp_port' => 490,
        'crlf' => "\r\n",
        'newline' => "\r\n"
      ));


$this->email->from('email', 'name');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->cc($cc);
$this->email->bcc('email');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
```